# understand minified javascript code

Tags: javascript, minify

I came across this piece of JS code on a minified library that is puzzling me:

```
...
return e.input || L(), e.addTest = function(a, b) {
...
```

I played with it on a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BNj7/1/) without much luck understanding what is happening.

I would like to know:

1. when does it return? always apparently.
2. what does it return? on my test it returns undefined... why?
3. when is the code L() executed? Only if e.input returns false?
4. when is e.addTest set? according to my test always... why?

Comment: What exactly would you like to know? What is `e.input || L()` or why there is a comma after `L()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*1. when does it return?*
always.

*2. what does it return? on my test it returns indefined... why?*
if you alert `alert` it alerts `undefined`

*3. when is the code L() executed?*
if `e.input` is false

*4. when is e.addTest set?*
The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

This is the unminified code in your case:

```
if (e.input) {
    L();
}
e.addTest = function(a, b) {};
return e.addTest;
```

Comment: +1 I've never even seen the comma as an operator. Thanks for this explanation.

Comment: +1 Same here. That is handy.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong :) , but I think you made a mistake on your last answer. If the comma operator evaluates both operands, shouldn't e.addTest always be set? That seems to be what is happening on my tests.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your code looks like this:

```
return e.input || L(), e.addTest = function(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

This code will:

1. Evaluate `e.input || L()`

   - This means that `L` will run if `e.input` is not falsy (`undefined`, `0`, `false`, `null`, empty string)
2. Evaluate `e.addTest = function(a, b) { ... }`

   - This stores a new function in `e.addTest`
   - Then, yields that function for the whole expression, so that function is returned

You can think of this as:

```
return ( ( e.input || L() ), e.addTest = function() { ... } )
```

where the `||` operation is done first, followed by the assignment operation.

This is because:

- The `||` operator is short-circuting, and will yield its first non-falsy operand

  - So `return a || b` returns `a` if `a` is truthy or otherwise returns `b`
- The `,` operator evaluates both operands to the left and right, but then yields the right operand

  - So `return a(), b()` runs both `a()` and `b()` but returns the result of `b()`
- The assignment operation yields the value assigned

  - So `return a = 5` will store `5` in `a` and then return `5`

In your case, you see `undefined` because the return value of `alert` is always `undefined`.

Comment: It always returns the function even if `e.input` is truthy. I've +1 because you added some things I didn't explain.

Comment: @A1rPun Thanks, edited to correct for the appropriate precedence of `||` and `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is entirely incomplete..

For help with minified code you can use [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/) site, they turn minified code into expanded code that's significantly easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that if e is undefined or false, then return L(), otherwise return e.addTest (where e.addTest is defined as follows).

ETA: just saw your edits. A1rPun explains it well.